# Site deployed with yeoman/grunt shows up mysterious black box

Tags: html, css, gruntjs, yeoman

The following black box appears in the top right hand corner of my page on my site set up with yeoman and grunt:

[image: black box]

This is what shows up in dev tools: [image: dev tools]
...although it's nowhere to be found in the original markup, or the page source.

I can't figure out what `__bs_notify__` is, and there's no reference to it in my HTML or CSS.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is BrowserSync notification bar. The markup is injected by BrowserSync proxy or static file server. Try to view the website without BrowserSync and this notification should go away.